# Deleting log files windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, windows-7

I need to make a batch file that can search the hard-drive for log files and remove them. Does any one know a code that I can use. I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that all *.log files on a drive can be deleted with no after effects, then this will delete the log files that are not in use:

```
@echo off
del \*.log /s /f /q
```